# Why embed iOS TypeForm iframe can submit survey without iOS iframe cookie restriction?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, safari, typeform

I have a website with an HTML form which can be embedded for my users' website, but my users have trouble submitting the embedded form at iOS or desktop safari device.

Turns out Safari has a restriction for iframe cookie, you can't just easily do that, but TypeForm can successfully submit the form when embedded in an iframe at the iOS device.

How did they do that? I have checked the Network tab of TypeForm, their API call did use cookie.

How did they achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

They didn't even block cors, I've figured it out.

Comment: How did you figure it out? I'm having a similar issue trying to embed a vue/laravel form within an iframe of my own Shopify site. It works fine on everything but iOS / safari.